.NET 7.0, ajax and sessions
I have a web app in .NET 7.0, which is mainly one single webpage (Index), with severals partials views :

one the first call to Index with some parameters, the session is first cleared, then the controller and services load some data from a database, store it in sessions, then send id back to the client.
then the differents partials views calls back the server (sometimes with aditional data, sometimes not), that get some data from the session, to get more data from services and database. Some of those partial views are called as soon as the page loads, and some after a user action.

All of that works perfectly on my environnement or on a test server with a few users, but on production environnement, with 100 users (whitch isn't that much), once in a while (several times a days), a user will have some sessions mixup, with a partial view that load data from the previous session ... And it's usually from the partial views  that are loaded at the begining.
The only time that I write a session variable is on the first call (in the Index Action), just after I cleared it.
I can't figure out why that would happen...
Here is the relevent part of my program.cs :

try
{

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Host.UseSerilog();


    builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration);

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddNegotiate()
                    .AddCookie();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    builder.Services.......
    builder.Services.......
    builder.Services.......


    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.Name = "DiscoursClient.Session";
    });


    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();



    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseSession();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/newcom/Index")
        {
            context.Session.Clear();
        }

        await next();
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

I should add that i'm using this package https://aspnet-core-grid.azurewebsites.net/ and that the partials views that seem to have the issue are called with the command @Html.AjaxGrid...
Does anyone has any idea what could go wrong ? Am I wrong in my understanding of the architecture ?

could you please share small reproducible sample with us

Well... I don't really know how to do that without giving you the whole app... besides, I haven't been able to reproduce it in dev environnement.

can we say, we got error from this app after publishing it to Azure web app? The error looks like session mix up?

nop, the app is on a IIS on a VM on-premise
